# Setting a Function Equal to Something

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting a VB.Net program to C#. The programmer who wrote the VB.Net code left so I cannot ask him for help, and I have very little knowledge of VB.net. In his program he has the following:

```
public DataSet getData(string SQL)
{

  'Some variable declarations
  Dim ds As New DataSet

  Try
    'Some code
    getData = ds 'This is the part of the code I am having trouble figuring out.

  'some more code
}
```

So getData is the name of the function and he is setting it to "ds" within itself. So my question is, why would you set the function equal to something within itself? And what would be the correct C# version of "getData = ds"?

Comment: that is the old style way to set the function return for VB6 type apps.  the NET equiv would be `return ds`

Comment: I hope `getData` is not the actual name of the function. Otherwise I kind of know why the programmer had to leave.

Comment: Note that this old-style syntax does not return immediately - it just sets the result to return when the function does exit, so if you just replace these with a 'Return', you'll have problems. The safest way is to set a new temp variable to the result and return that when the function exits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is some VB syntax that means that the return value of the function is `ds`. `return ds;` would be the equivalent in C#

From [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx), you can see that this is a valid return method in VB (emphasis mine)

> Returning from a Function
>
> When the Function procedure returns to the calling code, execution
>   continues with the statement that follows the statement that called
>   the procedure.
>
> **To return a value from a function**, you can either **assign the value to
>   the function name** or include it in a Return statement.

However I find this makes the code quite hard to read, so i tend to stay away from it and prefer the return

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. This guy's programming is really weird, because he also uses they keyword return in other sections of his code. He's not consistent at all.

Comment: its entirely possible that the app started out as a pre-Net app and that is just an artifact. @Jared.Rodgers

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, this way of returning data is a remnant from pre .Net VB, so it's entirely possible that there was a rewrite effort on some parts but not others.